# Internal use of IProgressMonitor in Eclipse plugin, good practice?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

TL;DR: My question is whether it is good practice to use the [`IProgressMonitor`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FIProgressMonitor.html) interface for **internally** keeping track of progress, or that it is purely meant for giving progress feedback to the user.

In the internals of the Eclipse plugins I am developing, there are a couple of (mostly) background tasks. For example, parsing some input (e.g. from a file), and filling a database with the results. Some of these tasks are run on a dedicated thread created by the plugin, another is run as a Job.

For all tasks, there are other plugin components (let's call them *interested parties*) that need to keep track of the tasks' progress and state, such as the percentage of work done, whether they are completed and whether they are running or paused (suspended).

The Job has, per its [`run`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/Job.html#run(org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor))  method, a progress monitor (`IProgressMonitor`), used to display a progress bar in the UI and to allow the user to cancel the Job.

The notion of progression used by the `IProgressMonitor` interface overlaps to a significant extent with the information the *interested parties* require.

Therefore, it seems to make sense to use that interface to inform the *interested parties*, by adding additional `IProgressMonitor`s to the Job. One monitor would be added for each *interested party*, and together all monitors can be wrapped in a single [`ProgressMonitorWrapper`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FProgressMonitorWrapper.html) that updates all monitors when work is being done. Example:

```
Job aJob = new Job("My long-running operation...") {
  protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    IStatus status = Status.OK_STATUS;
    IProgressMonitor wrappedMonitor = new ProgressMonitorWrapper(monitor) {
        // override everything so that you can report it locally, too
        public void beginTask(String name, int totalWork) {
            super.beginTask(name, totalWork);
            someLocalMonitor.beginTask(name, totalWork);
        }
    };
    wrappedMonitor.beginTask("foo", 100);
    try {
        // Execute, update amount of work done, etc.
    }
    finally {
        wrappedMonitor.done();
    }
    return status;
  };
});
```

(Copied and adapted from the Eclipse wiki. [Source](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/EAS/Progress_Service))

A similar approach could be used in the thread spawned by our plugin.

However, I'm not experienced enough to determine whether this is an appropriate use of the `IProgressMonitor` interface. The alternative, of course, is creating a custom listener interface (which, like the  `IProgressMonitor`, would require a notion of 'work done' to keep track of progress).

Comment: IProgressMonitor has quite a lot of methods (such as isCanceled and internalWorked) which don't really apply to what you want to use it for so maybe a custom interface would be better.

Comment: @greg Thanks for your (as always) quick reply. It doesn't really answer the question of whether using an `IProgressMonitor` outside its, automatic usage in Eclipse (in `IProgressService` / `Jobs` API) is valid practice.

That said, the fact that there are methods that are not appliccable to the use case is a really good, more practical point. So it's probably not the best idea to use `IProgressMonitor` in this case, regardless of whether it would be good practice to use it for internal progress tracking.